# maven-assembly-plugin fails to execute when including application dependencies

Tags: jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a very unusual case where the `maven-assembly-plugin` will not execute for `Scheduler` if I include dependencies of my `main-project` module.

`maven-assembly-plugin` fails to create .zip file, because `Scheduler` has a dependency on my `main-project` module, which in turn depends on many other modules.
`Scheduler` is a stand-alone application that runs on a separate machine that I wanted to bundle everything it needs in a zip file and deploy it using Jenkins.

The error I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single (Scheduler-assembly) @ Scheduler---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/assembly/src.xml
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single (Scheduler-assembly) on project Scheduler: Execution Scheduler-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
```

pom file:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>Scheduler</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Scheduler-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

assembly xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>

    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com.caci:TaskScheduler:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT</exclude>
                <exclude>jdom:jdom:jar:1.0</exclude>
                <!--<exclude>com.caci:dol-web</exclude>-->
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

If I remove `<dependencySets>` it creates zip file but without `lib` folder with it's dependencies.

Can someone shed some light, since I am burned. I have been looking at it for a long time :(